# ARR Load Balance with two Machines - Always redirect to same Site

Tags: web-server, load-balancing, iis-8, arr, nlb

described steps for each setup.

1. Created a sample Application WebShareTest , hosted the application in M1(IP 36) on port (80) and same Binary I hosted in M2(IP 210) (on port 8070)
2. I pointed some domain name like `my.joy` to the machine M1 ip 36
3. Installed ARR in M1 and added ServerFarm for the machines M1(port 80) & M2 (port 8070)
4. Added the following condition in M1 machine URL Rewrite Module (Machine level not in site level)

after I restarted the websites, when I launch application from the Browser it always redirect to M1 site. I choosed Round Robin Algorithm in IIS. Please help me what went wrong

Comment: Can you share more details about your setup?  Your step 4 doesn't show the actual condition you created.

Answer (score 0):

Without additional details, my best guess is that your Rewrite condition is being bypassed/ignored.  Since your app is already hosted on M1:80, it just works but always hits M1.  It might be easier to debug if you host your app on a different web site on M1, for example M1:8070.  Once you get your URL Rewrite rule working, you'll probably also need to add a condition that the rule should only fire on port 80, to avoid redirect loops.

I'd also say this setup is not recommended (having ARR with Server Farms and your app on the same machine), since for Server Farms the rewrite rules need to be at the machine level (as you noted in your question).  You're better off hosting ARR on a separate machine if you can.